# theming ubercart checkout fields

Tags: 6, theming, ubercart

I would like to add some extra html/text to one of delivery address fields - phone number. Wha twould be the best way of doing that? Would this code be of a help?http://api.ubercart.me/api/drupal/ubercart!uc_cart!uc_cart_checkout_pane.inc/function/theme_address_pane/6

Thank you.

Comment: That approach should be OK if you just want to add some text or embed some element in a tag, for example.
If you want to add or remove fields you might want to use `hook_form_alter`.

Comment: @Oliver I want only to add text under delivery phone field. Now I just need to find out how to do that:)

Comment: This might help: http://www.ubercart.org/docs/user/32119/how_theme_checkout_pane_ubercart_3
Depending on how far in the development process you are, you might want to consider using `drupal commerce` instead. As I understand it, UC is no longer actively maintained and docs are not great.

Comment: UC is still actively maintained - the last update was only a week ago...